# A fast way to multiply a NumPy array of scalars by an array of arrays

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, array-broadcasting, elementwise-operations

What is the most concise way to carry out multiplication like this?

```
# c's are scalars (or arrays like A's in general)
x = np.array([c1, c2, c3])
# A's are NumPy arrays
M = np.array([A1, A2, A3])
```

to get

```
x*M = [c1*A1, c2*A2, c3*A3]
```

c's are scalars, A's are NumPy numerical multidim arrays (let's say, matrices).

---

Example code:

```
x = np.array([1,2,3])
A = np.random.rand(2,2)
M = np.array([A,A,A])
```

Comment: What's the shape and datatype of `M`? Do all *sub-arrays* in `M` have the same shapes?

Comment: And `dtype` of `M`? Is it a 1d array of objects, or a multidimensional array of numbers?

Comment: @hpaulj Let's suppose they are multidimensional arrays of numbers - for simplicity - 2D matrices stored as `np.array`. Why does it matter? Scalar can be multiplied by almost anything, can't it?

Answer (score 2):

If M is a numpy array of primitive numeric types, (i.e. not objects), to take advantage of the numpy broadcasting, you can add dimensions to `x` so it has the same number of dimensions as `M`, and then the element-wise multiplication should work:

```
x.reshape((-1,) + (1,)*(M.ndim - 1)) * M
```

---

```
x = np.array([1,2,3])
```

2D case:

```
M = np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)    
x.reshape((-1,) + (1,)*(M.ndim - 1)) * M
#array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
#       [ 8, 10, 12, 14],
#       [24, 27, 30, 33]])
```

3D case:

```
M = np.arange(12).reshape(3,2,2)
x.reshape((-1,) + (1,)*(M.ndim - 1)) * M
#array([[[ 0,  1],
#        [ 2,  3]],

#       [[ 8, 10],
#        [12, 14]],

#       [[24, 27],
#        [30, 33]]])
```

Comment: Thanks, this one works. But the readability... It took me a while to understand what's happening :)

Answer (score -1):

product = [x[i]*M[i] for i in range(len(x))]

Comment: Or like this: `[A*c for (A,c) in zip(M,x)]`. Anyway, I believe that comprehensions are slower.